# Why does XHR have a memory leak when the page jumps?

Tags: javascript

Browser:IE 11.0.9600.19326

When there is a long link XHR request on the page, a memory leak occurs when you click # to navigate. The leak caused by the timer can be ruled out because no leak will occur before the jump #.

[image]

My Code:

```js
var isGetDataBusying = false;

function GetData() {
  if (isGetDataBusying == true) {
    return;
  } else {
    isGetDataBusying = true;
  }
  var xhr = null;
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/test.txt", true);
  xhr.timeout = 1000;
  xhr.onload = success;
  xhr.onloadend = end;
  xhr.send(null);

  function success() {
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300 || xhr.status == 304) {} else {}
  }

  function end() {
    xhr = null;
    isGetDataBusying = false;
  }
}

setInterval(GetData, 2);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>XHR Memory Leak</title>
</head>

<a href="#">#</a>

</html>
```

A high-performance computer is needed to ensure testing, because I found that on some computers with low performance, even if I don't click the # link, it will leak. But the leaked memory is different from the content after clicking the # link.

Comment: You're suggesting this happens in all browsers?

Comment: I am sorry, IE11.

Comment: i don't know the program or what program that is, how did you conclude that piek is a memory leak in IE11? And not extra needed memory to do the XML request in IE11?

Comment: Before I clicked #, I tested for 24 hours, the memory was steady, but when I clicked #, the memory started to rise.

Comment: Change the reference to "this" instead of "xhr" on the success function in order to avoid cross references, and try to declare the xhr var outside the GetData function (just in case). You should be fine after this.

Comment: The test failed.

Comment: So if it's just happening in one browser, then the "why" is that it's a bug. This isn't really a programming question. If you found this behavior across multiple implementations, then I could see it, but since this is an outlier, it's a platform-specific issue.